# Updating values in mysqlu for various values

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a question.

I would like to change a value of certian column in SQL, now I know how to do that, but before I would do that I would export those values into CSV, now afterwards I would like to import those values back into SQL again, so that nothing has changed. How could I do that?

The table in question has about 5000 rows, so unless I can change just 1 column back I would have to dump the table, change the values, then after I am done destroy the table and import the dump back in. Is there any easier way?

Comment: if you want to do update on duplicate you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214063/if-exists-update-else-insert-csv-data-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Please use **mysql** backend with a CLI tool (eg: Windows use CMD).
My simple example is like this:
- I'm creating a table named Test and populating it with few rows:

```
create table test
( col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(20), col3 varchar(30)
);

Insert into test values
('nice', 'good', 'well'),
('best', 'bad', 'great'),
('cute','love','alone');
```

- Then, I'm exporting the table on a csv file:

> ```
> >    SELECT * 
> >     FROM test
> >     INTO OUTFILE 'C://ProgramData//MySQL//MySQL Server 5.7//Uploads//test.csv'
> >         FIELDS TERMINATED BY '#'
> >         LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
> ```

Please, in order to find the right directory - you should replace mine C://... with yours - where you are allow to save your outputs use this command (working for any OS) :

> `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`

- Then, go to your directory and then modify your stuff. After that, delete all the old data : delete from test;
- Then load the **test.csv** file:

  > ```
  > LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C://ProgramData//MySQL//MySQL Server 5.7//Uploads//test.csv'
  > INTO TABLE test
  > FIELDS TERMINATED BY '#'
  > LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
  > ```

Hope that help.